# Some secret service is taking over port 80... I can't identify which one?

Tags: debian, nginx, http

I have an nginx service that resides on ports 80 and 443 and has done som for years. Yesterday I suddenly just got a plain text page with a **404 page not found** message

#### Headers:

```
HTTP/2 404
content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-length: 19
date: Sun, 01 Jan 2023 10:24:28 GMT
```

In order to troubleshoot, I started a terminal on another pc and started `watch curl -ksI https://trausti.local`

The output of that terminal window remained unchanged, even though i stopped the nginx service `sudo service nginx stop`. I verifíed this with

to figure out which other process might have overtaken the port, I ran these commands:

`netstat -tulpn | grep :80`

> $ netstat -tulpn | grep :80
> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8086            0.0.0.0:*                 LISTEN      -
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*                 LISTEN      -
> tcp6       0      0 :::8086                 :::*                      LISTEN      -
> tcp6       0      0 :::8088                 :::*                      LISTEN      -

`ss -lptr`

Both with no indication of the culprit...

I verified that the nginx service was stopped with `sudo systemctl status nginx`:

> ● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
> Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset:   enabled)
> Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2023-01-01 11:15:05 CET; 5min ago
> Docs: man:nginx(8)
> Process: 572 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Process: 935 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Process: 124643 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exite>
> Main PID: 936 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> CPU: 374ms

Jan 01 00:45:13 Trausti systemd[1](https://k3s.io/): Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jan 01 00:45:22 Trausti systemd[1](https://k3s.io/): Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Jan 01 11:15:03 Trausti systemd[1](https://k3s.io/): Stopping A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Jan 01 11:15:05 Trausti systemd[1](https://k3s.io/): nginx.service: Succeeded.
Jan 01 11:15:05 Trausti systemd[1](https://k3s.io/): Stopped A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

The only new service I have installed recently is [k3s](https://k3s.io/) and that is a couple of days ago.

I restarted the server completely at 00:45 which returned the normal nginx webpage, but now it is back at **404 page not found**

`uname -a` output:
*`Linux Trausti 5.10.0-20-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.158-2 (2022-12-13) x86_64 GNU/Linux`*

### Edit:

as @steve suggested it was related to k3s. Specifically the [Traefik Ingress controller and reverse proxy](https://docs.k3s.io/networking#traefik-ingress-controller) I am still very curious as to how it manages to hijack the ports withyout anything showing up. (and iritated that there were NO HEADERS WHATSOEVER indicating which service it is).

I still wonder at how it can listen on port 80 and 443 without turning up in `ss` or `netstat`

Comment: what does `sudo netstat -alntp|grep ':80'` say? any help about the process there?

Comment: @stoney just another couple of processes listening on 8088 and 8086

Comment: You should run this as root, you might not see all procesws info otherwise (as netstat stated). On a side note: could it be some kind of proxy that is interfering?

Comment: sudo does run it as root ;-)

Comment: You could have an effect that's basically similar to what `k3s` had by e.g. using iptables DNAT or REDIRECT targets to reroute connections incoming to a particular port towards a new target. Since all this happens below the application protocol layer (HTTP/2), there is no inherent requirement to generate any headers or other indications, as these manipulations are *intended* to be not detectable by the applications whose traffic is being manipulated.

Comment: so basically you are saying that if I set up appropriate rules in `iptables` or `dnat` I can redirect traffic to another service running on a userspace port, with only the userspace prt being visible in `ss` or `netstat` ?

Comment: Exactly. You could redirect traffic to any port, or even forward it to another host entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because k3s ingress is forwarding incoming port 80 to some other port.

k3s has setup a firewall rule so that anything targetting port 80 gets sent to another port, which k3s is then listening on.

As designed.

Comment: How can it take over the port when nginx had it, and why does starting nginx not cause a _port in use_ error?

Comment: besides that `sudo service stop k3s-agent` does not make the 404 page go away

Comment: but `sudo k3s-killall.sh` did make the 404 page disappear